# Rails cache get all values of a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached, dalli

I have a rails application where I am implementing caching using memcached and dalli.

I am storing results in hash like this

```
Rails.cache.write("home_stays[#{home_stay['id']}]", home_stay, expires_in: 5.minutes)
```

I can fetch value for a particular homestay using it's id.

What I am confused about is how can I get all homestays from the cache.

If I run Rails.cache.fetch("home_stays"), I get nil.

Is there a way to get all values of a cached hash in rails ?

update: 
As per Chakreshwar's suggestion I have added following in homestay model.

```
  def self.home_stay_cache
    Rails.cache.fetch("all_home_stays",expires_in: 5.minutes) do
      all
    end
  end
```

On running HomeStay.home_stay_cache I get following

```
Cache read: all_home_stays ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
Cache generate: all_home_stays ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
NameError: undefined local variable or method `all' for Homestay:class
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the below in the model:
 I am assuming that you are in the HomeStay model

```
def self.home_stay_cache
    Rails.cache.fetch("all_home_stay", expires_in: 5.minutes) do
      all
    end
end
```

Then , you can fetch it like `HomeStay.home_stay_cache`

Comment: Tried this and got
Cache read: all_home_stays ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
Cache generate: all_home_stays ({:expires_in=>300 seconds})
NoMethodError: undefined method `all' for #<Bookings::HomeStaysController:0x0000000735b3d8>
from (pry):13:in `block in index'

Comment: @RamanM: I just tried this in my model & its working , so I need your model to help u

Comment: Had gone for lunch.

Comment: check question now

Comment: You haven't used my complete code, You need to write the do block

Comment: Still no success !